# How to evaluate a function on all solutions given in output of a Reduce function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Say I have a Mathematica programme/function $f[z_,w_{} ] = \mathrm{Reduce}[\cdots]$ which outputs a list of solutions, which looks something like $$a =  1 \&\& ((0\leq b \leq 1000 \&\&  -5 \leq c \leq 65))  $$
$$a =  2 \&\& ((32\leq b \leq 860 \&\&  -4 \leq c \leq 36))  $$
and so on for all cases of $a$ (here $1 \leq a \leq 10$). Here $a,b,c$ are all integers.

I have another function $g$ written in Mathematica taking values in four integers that I would like to evaluate on each solution in the list above. Is it possible to write code which does this in Mathematica? I have searched online but haven't had much luck. Thanks!

Comment: (1) is $d$ missing by accident? (2) Also is this actually a list of solutions, or an `Or` of solutions? (3) it would probably help to have the output itself, or a simplified form of it, as actual code for copying/pasting! (4) also: what numbers exactly do you hope to evaluate `g` on, if `b` and the like are only specified up to bounds? or would you like the image of the entire interval under `g`?

Comment: @thorimur Hi, thanks for your reply! Yes thanks, I added $d$ by accident. Yes, it's a list - Mathematica outputs it the way I've written (with the double "and" symbols). Yes sorry, I forgot to specify this - $a,b,c$ are integers so I hope to evaluate $g$ on each discrete solution in the list. So for the updated question, I'd hope to evaluate $g$ on $(a,b,c)=(1,0,-5), (1,0,-4)$ and so on.

Comment: The function `ToRules` will change the output of `Reduce` to rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
g[a,b,c] /. Solve[f[z,w], {a,b,c}, Integers]
```

You may need to surround it with a `Block` if you have `a`,`b`,`c` defined elsewhere:

```
Block[{a,b,c},
  g[a,b,c] /. Solve[f[z,w], {a,b,c}, Integers]
]
```

If indeed `f` outputs a list, you may also need to replace the `List` head with an `Or` head, or map over the list of solutions for each case of `a` if you want a list of lists:

```
Block[{a,b,c},
  g[a,b,c] /. Solve[Or @@ f[z,w], {a,b,c}, Integers]
]

Block[{a,b,c},
  (g[a,b,c] /. Solve[#, {a,b,c}, Integers]) & /@ f[z,w]
]
```

Let me know if it works! :)

Comment: Hi, apologies for my late response, and thanks very much for your reply! :) Yes, I think this will work. Unfortunately, I realised earlier today that applying the second function $g$ doesn't solve the problem that I'm trying to solve correctly, but it's useful to know how to combine the output of a Reduce function with another function for the future. Thanks again! :)